# Visual Studio 2015 breaks on exceptions even though my Exception Settings are empty

Tags: c#, visual-studio, exception

So my question is pretty much the title. MY VS keeps breaking on exceptions even though my exception settings are all clear. I don't want it to break on these exceptions, and the rest of my team, which have the same setup in exception settings, do no break at the same time I do.

Is there any background folder in VS i need to delete so it can be remade or something similar? Is it caching something? I'd love some input on this. Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that your exception is not an *unhandled* exception? Because you can't prevent breaking on *unhandled* exceptions.

Comment: intresting... had the same issue today with vs2015 U3 - i threw an exception out of my application and caught them at another place... but vs always breaks (and continues fine by pressing F5) - my explicit version: 14.0.25425.01 Update 3 - i think it had something todo with the fact that i changed the exception settings during the debug session

Comment: Start debugging. Press "CTRL + D, E" to show exception settings dialog or find it via quick launch. The IDE always breaks for any checked exception (handled/unhandled not matters.) [msdn reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x85tt0dd.aspx)

Comment: Yeah I am @bitbonk, because I got the exact same code as the rest of my team, and they don't have this issue with the same setup in Exception Settings as I do. If they check on CLR Exceptions then they get the same ones as I do, even though mine is unchecked.

Comment: You may ask a team member to export the settings (import export settings in tools). Now you can compare with a text comparer (winmerge etc) with your exported settings. The settings file is plain xml. You may also try to delete any *.suo files, maybe...

Comment: Where can I find the *.suo files? Willing to try anything about now..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It solved itself in a VS update. No longer have these issues. Must have been a bug somewhere.